# Simple alert toggle inside php

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to figure out how when I click a button, a small dialogue box will appear displaying the echo $var information inside of my php.

I have html with php displaying. I'm able to echo individual variables where I want them no problem, but I want to hide the phone and email behind an onclick contact button. Here's the extent of my coding knowledge attempt:

THANKS!

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo "<section class='content'>";
            echo "<div class='section group'>";
            echo "<div class='col span_1_of_3'>";
            echo "<div class='card'>";
            echo "<h2 class='name'>";
            echo $row['Fname'] . " ";
            echo $row['Lname'];
            echo "</h2>";
            echo "<section class='profile'>";
            echo "<h3>Interests:</h3> ";
            echo $row['Interest1'] . ", ";
            echo $row['Interest2'] . ", ";
            echo $row['Interest3']  . "<br>";
            echo "<h3>Website:</h3> ";
            echo $row['Website']  . "<br>";
            echo "<h3>Personal Statement:</h3> ";
            echo "<aside class='statement'>";
            echo "<p>";
            echo $row['PersonalStatement'] . "<br><br>";
            echo "</p>";
            echo "</aside>";
            echo "<button class='contact-details' button id='contact' onclick='toggle_visibility('contact')'";
            echo "Contact";
            echo "</button>";

            echo "</section>";
            echo "</div>";
            echo "</div>";
            echo "</div>";
            echo "</body>";
            echo "</html>";
            ?>
                <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#contact").click(function(){
        alert("<?php echo $row['Phone'];?>"'<br>'
        "<?php echo $row['Email'];?>");
        exit;
        });
    });
        </script>
```

Comment: PHP runs _before_ HTML output. So it's not possible to alert dynamic PHP variables with Javascript. Instead, you'll need to look at Ajax. This will allow you to send and retrieve information from a PHP file through Javascript without the need to refresh your website.

Comment: have you tried to `echo` the script itself like what you have done with HTML

Comment: @g33k I have tried that. As I recall, php didn't like that there was an echo inside of an echo. I think I was also lost in either splitting up the function between echos or being able to fit it all into one. If someone can help me see how it's supposed to go, I can try that.

icecub Bare with my understanding; I don't think I'm trying to alert dynamic php variables. These variables can run/load before html--great! They just would be hidden underneath the contact button, awaiting to be clicked to be revealed. Does that make sense?

Comment: Where is the phone and number? $(/*selector here*/).hide();

Comment: You can "alert dynamic php variables" its not a good practice but you can.

Comment: @Emeeus That is the jQuery? I put that in and it just hides the contact button. As for you asking where the phone and email are, what exactly do you mean where? They are $row['Phone'] and $row['Email']. They aren't inside the echos in the above code. But they are in the script.

Comment: @StevenGuerrero yes, its jquery. you need some selector (id, class, somethig) to tell js what to hide.

Comment: Wow there is a lot wrong with this, before you get to echo. You are looping a data set and closing the document and html, then adding a script. I would fix the basic's first.. sorry, but this looks like a world of pain.

Comment: Shaun, your comment is in no way helpful. It's as if you said it only to point out that you could do it better. Congratulations. I've found my own solution. stackoverflow continues to show a large amount of elitism in coding...

Comment: @StevenGuerrero why not using `Smarty` ?

Answer (score 0):

While I got the toggle to work, aesthetically it didn't appeal to me as it did in theory. I'm just going with revealing the content as a standard.